# replace numbers - powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0

Trying to create a script which organizes each filename into: Year, Month & Day variables.

To do this in PowerShell with my current version I need to use `-replace` however it will only remove numbers from right to left.

How do I replace the first 4 digits which in this case would be something like this: `20181015`

```
$Month = $FileNameArray -replace "^2018"
$Month = $FileNameArray -replace "..$"
```

Output:

```
201801...201802...201803...201804...201805...201806...201807...201808...201809...2018010...2018011...2018012...
```

`...` represents repeating instances of the same number.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want to achieve? What is the *input* string? Please provide a real life example.

Comment: Also are you really doing this in powershell v2?

Comment: Your telling me! The boss wants us to use v2, I'm already on 4.0 and made a script that works within that version :(

Comment: As for what I'm trying to achieve, I need to create set of directories/folders based on the output an example filepath for 20180101 would be 2018/01/01

Comment: You should not be using replace at all. The best option is to treat the string as a date and use the .Net methods to parse the date parts in my opinion. Failing that you should just be getting substrings of the date string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lost one parameter. 

There're 2 parameters for operator `-replace`, the first one is source, and the second one is the target, separated by comma.

```
"20181015" -replace "^2018","9999"
```

This will output `99991015`, the source supports regex.

Comment: How would I replace it with nothing

Comment: Just keep the 2nd parameter empty, like this: `"20181015" -replace "^2018"`, You will get `1015` . If you need more answer, it's recommended to post some of the source, and result you expect. :)

Comment: Or is there another expression I could use besides `Trim()` as it is not supported in v2

Comment: If you just want the month, try this: `"20181015" -replace "^\d{4}|\d{2}$"`, BE SURE the format of the source is exactly match _yyyymmdd_.

Comment: (?) "`Trim()` is not supported in v2" - not correct.

Comment: Also, if you are looking to get the date parts from a date, just parse the date: `$date = [datetime]::parseexact("20181015", "yyyyMMdd", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture); $day = $date.Day`

Comment: That Worked! I'm guessing `$Day` would be something like this: `"20181015" -replace "^\d{6}|\d{0}$"`

Comment: Just `"20181015" -replace "^\d{6}"`, you will get the "$Day", for `"20181015" -replace "\d{4}$"` for "$Year".

Answer (score 0):

I think I might be getting confused. I thought that your goal was to create a path based on a date. Given the date 20180101, you could create the path thusly:

```
$date = [datetime]::parseexact("20180101", "yyyyMMdd", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
$path = '{0}\{1:D2}\{2:D2}' -f $date.Year, $date.Month, $date.Day
```

There is no need to do any replacing.